# How can Enumerator stop in the middle of method execution?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

(Example is from Ruby Tapas episode. 59)

```
@names = %w[Ylva Brighid Shifra Yesamin]

def names
  yield @names.shift
  yield @names.shift
  yield @names.shift
  yield @names.shift
end

enum = to_enum(:names)
enum.next # => Ylva
@names    # => ["Brighid", "Shifra", "Yesamin"]
```

`names` method execution seems to stop after the first line. If `names` is executed entirely, `@names` should become empty. How can this magic (= calling method partially) happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected. On the invocation enum.next it calls the first line in the names method and then *yields* to the caller, i.e. stops the flow of execution of the names method at that point. On the next invocation enum.next the flow of execution is picked up from the point where it left off.

Ruby actually has an object called a Fiber which might demonstrate this more succinctly: http://apidock.com/ruby/Fiber They allow you to 'pause execution' at an arbitrary point in your program by calling `Fiber.yield` and `resume` where you left off at a later time.

For example, the example above:

```
@names = %w[Ylva Brighid Shifra Yesamin]
fiber = Fiber.new do
  Fiber.yield @names.shift # yields control to the caller
  Fiber.yield @names.shift
  Fiber.yield @names.shift
  Fiber.yield @names.shift
end

# the resume calls give control to the fiber at the point we left off
puts fiber.resume #=> Ylva
puts fiber.resume #=> Brighid
puts fiber.resume #=> Shifra
puts fiber.resume #=> Yesamin
```

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**

The docs for [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-to_enum) (same as `Object#enum_for`) explain that, when invoked without a block:

```
obj.to_enum(method = :each, *args)
```

the method "creates a new Enumerator which will enumerate by calling `method` on `obj`, passing `args`, if any. As this method is created on `Object` it can be invoked on any object, but there is no point in doing so if `each` is not defined on the object's class:

```
enum = 1.to_enum
enum.each { |i| puts "i" }
  #NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum
```

**Normal use**

One normally sees `to_enum` used with the default method argument `:each`, no arguments and explicit receiver:

```
obj.to_enum
```

and I would venture to say that `obj` is normally an array. In your question the method argument is not `:each` and the receiver is implicit, and therefore `self`, which equals `main`.

**How it works**

Once the enumerator `enum` is defined, if `each` is invoked on it with a block, each element of `enum` is passed to the block (and assigned to the block variable) and the block is evaluated.

The following sequence of operations should shed more light on how enumerators work:

```
a = [1,2,3]
enum = a.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each> 
enum.to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 
enum.each { |e| puts e }
  #-> 1
  #   2
  #   3
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 
a[0] = 'cat'
enum.to_a
  #=> ["cat", 2, 3] 
a.object_id
  #=> 70235487149000
a = []
a.object_id
  #=> 70235487117180
enum.to_a
  #=> ["cat", 2, 3] !!
a = [1,2,3]
enum = a.to_enum
a.replace([])
enum.to_a
  #=> []
```

By the way, I use the customary notation `#=>` to indicate what a method returns, and `#->` to indicate what is printed.

**Used with `loop do`**

Suppose:

```
enum = [1,2,3].to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
```

We can step through `enum` by invoking [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html) on it:

```
enum.next #=> 1 
enum.next #=> 2 
enum.next #=> 3 
enum.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
enum.rewind 
enum.next #=> 1
```

As you see, a `StopIteration` exception is raised when we attempt to move beyond the end of the enumerator.

It's often convenient to use [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html) with enumerators because `loop` handles the `StopIteration` exception by breaking out of the loop. For example:

```
enum = [1,2,3].to_enum
loop do
  puts enum.next
end
  #-> 1
  #   2
  #   3
  #=> nil
```

**Your `names` method, simplified**

The example you consider is a bit confusing because `@names` is being modified ("mutated").  Let's start with a simpler example:

```
def names
  yield "Lucy"
  s = "Billy-Bob"
  yield s
end
```

If we execute this with a block, there is no surprise:

```
def names
  yield "Lucy"
  s = "Billy-Bob"
  yield s
end

names { |s| puts "My name is #{s}" }
  #-> My name is Lucy
  #   My name is Billy-Bob
```

Now let's create an enumerator for the method:

```
enum = to_enum(:names)
  #=> #<Enumerator: main:names>
```

We can examine the contents of the enumerator by repeatedly invoking [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
enum.next #=> "Lucy" 
enum.next #=> "Billy-Bob" 
enum.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end (exception)
```

Do you see what is happening? Ruby is stepping through the method `names` and computing the parameter that is passed to the block each time `yield` is invoked.

We can invoke `each` on `enum`, with the same block as before:

```
enum.each { |s| puts "My name is #{s}" }
  #-> My name is Lucy
  #   My name is Billy-Bob
```

`each` merely passes each element of `enum` to the block.

**Your method `names`, finally**

Now let's look at the particular example you gave.

```
@names = %w[Ylva Brighid Shifra Yesamin]

def names
  yield @names.shift
  yield @names.shift
  yield @names.shift
  yield @names.shift
end
```

You know you can just invoke `names` with a block:

```
names { |s| puts "My name is #{s}" }
  #-> My name is Ylva
  #   My name is Brighid
  #   My name is Shifra
  #   My name is Yesamin
```

after which:

```
@names #=> []
```

Let's reinitialize `@names`:

```
@names = %w[Ylva Brighid Shifra Yesamin]
```

and create an enumerator on the method `names`:

```
enum = to_enum(:names)
  #=> #<Enumerator: main:names>
```

Now let's step through the enumerator with `next`, and at each step examine the value of `@names`:

```
enum.next # => @names.shift => "Ylva"
  # => "Ylva"
```

`next` caused Ruby to go to the first `yield` in `names` and compute and return the parameter to be passed to the block. As expected: `

```
@names    #=> ["Brighid", "Shifra", "Yesamin"]
```

Let's do it three more times:

```
enum.next #=> "Brighid" 
@names    #=> ["Shifra", "Yesamin"] 

enum.next #=> "Shifra" 
@names    #=> ["Yesamin"] 

enum.next #=> "Yesamin" 
@names    #=> []
```

Try once more:

```
enum.next #StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

All that should make sense now, but here's something that may suprise you:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

That's because:

```
[][0]   #=> nil
[][1]   #=> nil
[][999] #=> nil
```

Now lets send `each` to `enum` with the block we used earlier:

```
@names = %w[Ylva Brighid Shifra Yesamin]
enum.each { |s| puts "My name is #{s}" }
  #-> My name is Ylva
  #   My name is Brighid
  #   My name is Shifra
  #   My name is Yesamin
```

Did you notice that, while we needed to reinitialize `@names`, of course, we didn't have to recreate the enumerator?